# Adding 2 characters in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I am new to Scala and I was working on something,
I need to implement the following code

```
class $(val text2d: Array[Array[Char]]) {
  def +(that: $) = ...
}
```

But my code keeps giving me an error stating

> found   : Array[Array[Char]]
>    required: String

Here is what my code looks like:

```
class Point2D(val text2D : Array[Array[Char]]) {
  def +(that : Point2D): Point2D =
    new Point2D(text2D + that.text2D)

  override def toString = {
    s"${text2D}"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `++` method to join two arrays into a new one.

```
  class Point2D(val text2D: Array[Array[Char]]) {
    def +(that: Point2D): Point2D =
      new Point2D(text2D ++ that.text2D)
  }
```